# Understanding the period/cycle of time series data

Tags: time-series, python, statsmodels, multiple-seasonalities

I'm trying to understand the meaning of period/cycle length in time series forecasting. Some functions, such as `seasonal_decompose` and `STL` (Python `statsmodels` package) or models like SARIMA have a period or cycle parameter that indicates 'the period of the series' used (`period`, `seasonal`, etc). As I understand it, this would be the period after which the seasonal behaviour of the series repeats (according to [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/234601/)).

I'm working with web traffic data that was recorded in 1hour intervals over the span of 8-14 months. My layman's fourier analysis seems to indicate that the data's strongest underlying frequencies are: 24h, 335h (14 days), 675h (28 days), 3720h (155 days), 6h and 12h (in order).

Most online examples assume only 1 frequency in the data, usually as a yearly reoccurrence, and there seems to be little mention of special treatment for time series that have more than a yearly seasonal component. Is such special attention to multiple seasonalities commonly practiced? Is there pre-built code specifically designed for this or are 'single' period functions adapted in some way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, your understanding of period/cycle length is correct.

For hourly web traffic, I would expect the strongest seasonalities for cycles of length 24h (daily seasonality) and 168h (weekly seasonality - typically weekdays and weekends differ strongly). For instance, [here is traffic to CV](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3107/1352).

You have already found our [multiple-seasonalities](/questions/tagged/multiple-seasonalities) tag. Its [tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-seasonalities/info) contains pointers to literature and commonly used algorithms to model this. My impression is that most such specialized models are implemented in R, rather than Python, but I may be wrong about this.

STL and ARIMA can only deal with a single seasonal period. Depending on your data, you may learn a little something from applying these models separately with the two seasonalities. (E.g., a very simple forecast would be to fit separate ARIMA models for the two seasonalities, then average the forecasts.)